# GuzzleHttp and Laravel - Syntax error - T_String

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, guzzle

I am currently trying to use `GuzzleHttp` with Laravel to access an API based on the user's input.

My set-up so far:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client
        ->get('https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/'Input::get('postcode'));
dd($response->getBody());
```

but the error being returned is:

> FatalErrorException in ClinicController.php line 129: syntax error,
>   unexpected 'Input' (T_STRING)

Line 129 is `https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/'Input::get('postcode')`

Any help why this is occurring would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a simple PHP error.  Here's the line PHP is complaining about

```
->get('https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/'Input::get('postcode'));
```

You have a string

```
'https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/'
```

immediately followed by `Input::get('postcode')`.  If you're trying to combine these two, you'll want to use the `.` operator to concatenate the strings

```
 'https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/' . Input::get('postcode')
```

Also, something to consider -- in a production application, you'd want to either sanitize or validate that `Input::get('postcode')` actually contains a post code before using it in a URL request like that. Always assume someone will try to use your system maliciously, and never trust that user input will contain what you think it contains.

Comment: Thank you Alan, I thought `Input::` does sanitise all inputs? The postcode is passed through a `regular expression` checker prior to this being used.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below :

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
 $response = $client
        ->get('https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/'.Input::get('postcode'));
 dd($response->getBody());
```